# Как сделать эффект растущей цены (на подобие таймера)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице указана цена 126 рублей 00 копеек. Нужно эту цену каждую минуту увеличивать на 1 рубль. И также в течение минуты должны увеличиваться копейки, которые показывают, что цена растет. Как это можно реализовать? Если с рублями все понятно, используем setInterval и через каждые 60000мс пребавляем 1, то с копейками не могу сообразить.

Comment: Ровно также, как и с рублями, только вестимо, каждые 600мс прибавлять

Comment: Если у тебя рубли и копейки раздельны, в разных тегах, просто увеличивай всегда копейки. Получается, каждую секунду делай + 3 копейки, либо каждые 2 секунды + 6 копеек... Как только секунды становятся равны 60 - обнуляй копейки и делай +1 рублям.

Comment: `setInterval` не гарантирует точных интервалов, замучаетесь синхронизировать. Такие вещи **всегда** нужно самим через `Date` синхронизировать. У @vp_arth неплохой ответ.

Comment: @Anon а зачем, если можно каждые 100 копеек плюсовать рубль? Или это так важно, чтобы именно в эту минуту и секунду рубль перескочил, а не миллисекундой позже/раньше?

Comment: Дело не в том, когда и что плюсовать. Дело в том, что `setInterval` неизбежно уедет, и в минуту набежит не то, что вы ожидали.

Comment: @Anon я к тому, что нет смысла в таких штуках отмерять именно минуту. Он уедет не так сильно, что это может заметно повлиять на результат. А усложнять ради этого код, ну хз, спорный момент.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решение с неточным таймером.

```js
var price = 126.00;

updatePrice = function() {
  document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = XFormatPrice(price);
  price+=(100/60)/100;
}

updatePrice();

setInterval(updatePrice, 1000);

function XFormatPrice(_number) 
{
    var format_string = '# руб.';
 
    var r=parseFloat(_number)
 
    var exp10=Math.pow(10,2);
    r=Math.round(r*exp10)/exp10;
 
    rr=Number(r).toFixed(2).toString().split('.');
 
    b=rr[0].replace(/(\d{1,3}(?=(\d{3})+(?:\.\d|\b)))/g,"\$1"+' ');
 
    r=(rr[1]?b+ ',' +rr[1]:b);
    return format_string.replace('#', r);
}
```

```html
<div id="price"></div>
```

Comment: было же сказано `Если с рублями все понятно, то с копейками не могу сообразить.`

Comment: @SLy_huh Был невнимателен, поправил.

Comment: ток копейки прыгают. Если апдейтить каждую секунду, то получится 60 обновлений в минуту, за это время прибавляется рубль - 100 копеек. Т.е. 40/100 обновлений пользователь не увидит

Comment: @SLy_huh а где условие, что пользователь должен видеть все обновления?

Comment: А где условие, что пользователь должен видеть копейки? Ты бы еще каждую секунду копейки на 100 увеличивал и обнулял. Ну а что, увеличиваются же, условий тоже не было.

Comment: @SLy_huh а вот условие про копейки было :)

Comment: `Math.pow(10, 2)` - это `100`? Я ничего не путаю? Я бы написал `1e2`

Comment: @vp_arth форматирование цены я честно скопипастил с просторов интернета

Answer (score 12):

Нужно заякорить момент во времени(начало отсчёта) и связать его с ценой.
Потом можно часто вызывать функцию пересчёта, и обновлять цену, в зависимости от пройденного от начала времени.

```js
var costEl = document.getElementById('cost');
var velocity = 1/60; // рубль в минуту

var start = Date.now();
var startCost = parseFloat(costEl.innerText);

setInterval(function(){
  var now = Date.now();
  var secs = (now - start) / 1e3;
  var newCost = (startCost + secs*velocity).toFixed(2);
  costEl.innerText = newCost;
}, 100);
```

```html
<span id="cost">100.00</span>
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, не подскажите почему вы `secs` делите на 1000? Уже голову сломал, вижу что работает, а не могу до конца понять как..

Comment: `Date.now()` возвращает текущее время в миллисекундах

Comment: Ох, точно, спасибо :)

Answer (score 2):

```js
var velocity = 100;
setInterval(function(){
  var h = $('#hundredths').text();
  var r = $('#roubles').text();
  if(++h == 100){
    h = 0;
    r++;
  }
  
  $('#hundredths').text((h < 10 ? '0' : '') + h);
  $('#roubles').text(r);
}, velocity);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Цена, руб. <span id='roubles'>126</span>.<span id='hundredths'>00</span>
```

Comment: Всё, что мне не нравится в этом ответе - внутренний перфекционист) Тем не менее +1. Ну и ещё, хотелось бы способ, чтобы регулировать скорость)

Comment: @Anon спасибо. Просто не люблю громоздких решений для простых задач. Скорость по совету тоже добавил `=)`

Comment: `&#8381;` - я так понимаю символ рубля? Довожу до вашего сведения, что я его не вижу) `Ubuntu, Chrome`

Comment: @Anon, ладно, это тоже уберем, все же мы боремся за перфекционизм, а значит все должно отображаться везде по максимуму `=)`

Answer (score 1):

Используйте оператор `%` - остаток от деления:

Тест (ускорен):

```js
var x=0

setInterval(function(){
   x++
   console.log(x%100)
},60000/1000)
```

Comment: `console.log` может оказаться медленнее, чем вы от него требуете)